# Invite via hotmail contacts with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, hotmail

I need to send an invitation mail to hotmail contacts.
I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/mrThe/omnicontacts) gem for this. This works correctly for gmail and yahoo, but for hotmail it doesn't:

> Their API returns a Contact object, which does not contain an e-mail
>   field!

Then, I try to use [this](https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts) gem, but it's too old, and now does not work.
Official Microsoft documentation is poor, and I can't google some examples for this.

Are there any solutions for this? Maybe a different gem, api or something.

I'm using ruby-1.9.2 and rails 3.1.0 if it's important.

P.S. Sorry for my poor English, it's not my native language. Please, correct my post if something is wrong.

Comment: Also, i find this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/1fd1430e-e045-4481-b307-f7afb27fa36a/ but i have no idea how i can use it.

Comment: Hehe) I have same questions for my client, but he want this feature. But, because i still can't do it, i will be forced to give up.

Comment: Notice that linkedIn **does** retrieve your friends emails. How does it do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail uses live connect. More information about live connect can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live

It uses a REST Api with oauth communication.

More information about the rest api can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff748607.aspx

Edit: This is an overview / guide on how to implement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff752216.aspx